# No error in submitting a live paypal direct payment transaction but does not go through

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a donation page that utilizes both the options to pay with credit/debit cards directly or paypal express checkout option. Everything works great in the sandbox now when I connect with live credentials the payments through paypal express checkout work great!

The payments using direct payment with credit/debit cards however is not going through. On the page everything goes through perfectly (even gives me a transaction id for the payment from paypal) but if I check the credit card that does the payment or the paypal account that receives the payments they are not there.

Is there a step I am suppose to do before going live with utilizing the DoDirectPayment api (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) for the direct credit/debit card payments?

Comment: It sounds like you're still running through the Sandbox. Check your sandbox PayPal account to see if the transaction is there.

Comment: @Machavity hmm well ..that makes me feel a bit dumb, but yeah it did go through the sandbox account..weird I set it up to go through live. Anyways thanks for the information helped solve my predicament I will have to look at what is wrong with me code for not picking up live instead of sandbox credentials. You are free to answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Machavity lol apparently after changing my sandbox value to FALSE I did not save the file ...but the live works! Thanks for the info again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the transaction ran through the Sandbox anyways. Remember, the Sandbox will issue you Transaction ID just like the live system will. I would check the URL you submitted to, as well as your Sandbox PayPal account(s).